# Add values depending on answer

Tags: php, addition

I have these two files.

***A.php***

```
<?

   echo "
       <form action = 'B.php' method = 'post'>
          5+5 = ?
          Write answer: <input type = 'text' name = 'op1'>

           10+10 = ?
           Write answer: <input type = 'text' name = 'op2'>
       </form>

   ";
?>
```

***B.php***

```
<?

 $op1 = $_REQUEST ['op1'];
 $op2 = $_REQUEST ['op2'];

 if ($op1 == '10'){
     echo "Right answer. 2p.";
     $mark = '2';
 }else{
     echo "Wrong answer. 0p.";
     $mark2 = '0';
 }

 if ($op2 == '20'){
     echo "Right answer. 2p.";
     $mark3 = '2';
 }else{
     echo "Wrong answer. 0p.";
     $mark4 = '0';
 }

?>
```

How can I make an expression to make a total add?
I've written a simple example, mine has 20 operations, how can I do that depending on the answer add 2 points or 1 point or 0 and finally write the result?
(It's like an exam from 0 to 10)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a variable to 0 and then adding points.  This is the most basic way to add things together through your `if` statements.

```
<?php

 $op1 = $_REQUEST ['op1'];
 $op2 = $_REQUEST ['op2'];
 $total=0;
 if ($op1 == '10'){
     echo "Right answer. 2p.";
     $mark = '2';
     $total+=2;
 }else{
     echo "Wrong answer. 0p.";
     $mark2 = '0';
 }

 if ($op2 == '20'){
     echo "Right answer. 2p.";
     $mark3 = '2';
     $total+=2;
 }else{
     echo "Wrong answer. 0p.";
     $mark4 = '0';
 }
 echo "Total points: $total";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

While an answer is provided but I shall point out what is wrong with your code and that is, `PLENTY`.

First of all, why do you need to echo HTML when you can use HTML directly? Echoing large bits of HTML is one of the very practices that make code **UGLY**.

Secondly, You are using if statement for every question and answer. That makes no sense: To add 10 lines of code for every question.

Thirdly, do not ever use `$_REQUEST`.

I would advice to maintain, a db or an array of question and answers. For eg,

```
$q_array = Array(
     array(
        "question" => "abc",
        "answer" => "455",
     ),....
)
```

Then, you can echo the questions, and check for answers using a loop.

Comment: Nice points. Except for the `$_REQUEST` is bad meme; that needs to die. It's just a mix of GET and POST on current configurations. The cookie fixation issue (that I hope you were alluding to) is long past, and the scaremongering was hardly applicable to its common use cases.

Comment: @mario: I am not aware of cookie fixation issue. and the reason I keep away from `$_REQUEST` is beacuse brute forcing with "get" method is far more easier than `$_POST`.

Comment: That's true, but not a good eschewing reason. Smuggling params in per GET is easier from a webbrowser and via links (think `<img src="deleteuser.php?name=root">` as request forgerey exploit), but that doesn't make POST variables more secure; it's often a false sense of safety. OTOH, it's uneeded to allow dual-input at all times, so if a login form should only use POST, then only using $_POST makes sense. (For non-write APIs the mixed input is IMHO preferrable due to convenience.)

Answer (score 0):

**extension of shubam answer:**
 $q_array = Array(

```
"op1"=>"10",
op2=>"20"

)
```

**key of array is input type field name in form and values of array is the correct answer**

```
$total=0;
foreach($_REQUEST as $key=>$val)
{

if($q_array[$key]=$val)
{

     echo "Right answer. 2p.";
     $mark = '2';
     $total+=2;
     echo"<br>";

}


}

echo "Total points: $total";
```